# Simplification of time complexity notation

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I want to simplify a big O time complexity notation for my algorithm. The algorithm calculates relative distances between a subset of sampled nodes V<sub>s</sub> and all other nodes V in graph G through a single-source shortest path algorithm with time complexity O(V+E). This would result in an overall complexity of O(V(V<sub>s</sub>(V+E))) with practical implementation:

```
for node in V:
    for sampled node in Vs:
        single-source shortest path calculation(node, sampled node)
```

Can I simplify this to a complexity of O(V<sub>s</sub>(V<sup>2</sup>+VE)) which would then be approximately O(V<sup>3</sup>) ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: How large can $|V_s|$ be? If it can be as large as $|V|$, then with $E = O(V^2)$, the time complexity would be $O(V^4)$.